# DataGridView MouseWheel sendkeys updown issue

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview, scroll, mousewheel

i create a subclass datagridview to override the mousewheel event to catch mouse scroll then send key UP or DOWN. i create a datatable to be bind as datasource for mydatagridview by button click

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

        int NUM_ROWS = 150;
        int NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE; i++)
        {
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("x" + i, typeof(string));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
        {
            var theRow = myDataTable.NewRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE; j++)
            {
                theRow[j] = "whatever";
            }

            //add the row *after* populating it
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
        }

        MyDataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;
    }
```

the code that override the mousewheel event as this

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta < 0)
            SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        else
            SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
    }
}
```

Its working fine if we use mouse wheel to scroll each item in a SLOW way, but if you scroll too FAST using the mouse wheel, somewhat the datagridview becomes lagging.

As example from row 1 to 5, it will jump the row from 1 to 3,then 3 to 5 something like that, here come another weird issue. i use "Navicat" a lot in my daily basis..

so if i open both my application and Navicat. the mouse wheel scrolling now become very smooth on my application even if i scroll too fast. but then if i close Navicat then scrolling become lagging again. what was causing this? i am very sorry if i cant explained it well, all i want is just want to makes the scrolling each item smooth. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Bozhidar mentioned that i should better handling the MouseWheel event instead or overriding it. so i've come up with the solution just in case anyone need it too.

in Form_Load add

```
MyDataGridView1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(MyDataGridView1_MouseWheel);
```

then place this anywhere inside your class

```
private void MyDataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HandledMouseEventArgs hme = (HandledMouseEventArgs)e;
    hme.Handled = true;

    int rowIndex = MyDataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int cellIndex = MyDataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    MyDataGridView1.CurrentCell = MyDataGridView1.Rows[e.Delta < 0 ? Math.Min(rowIndex + 1, MyDataGridView1.RowCount - 1) : Math.Max(rowIndex - 1, 0)].Cells[cellIndex];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SendKeys` method is not as reliable when it comes to precise timing - see the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx). Try setting the "SendKeys" app setting to "SendInput" in order to force the new behavior.

But you'd be better off **handling** the `MouseWheel` event instead of *overriding* it. You need to hook it by hand - not sure why it isn't present into the Property Window. Given your `DataGridView` is named `dgv`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.MouseWheel += Dgv_MouseWheel;
}
```

Next, have you considered [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)? Just set it as appropriate in the event, and set the `Handled` flag, like this:

```
private void dgv_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex += 3;
    var he = (HandledMouseEventArgs);
    he.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. i cannot use the FirstDisplayerScrollingRowIndex because i want the current cell to be selected(highlight). the same way as pressing the UP or DOWN button.

Comment: Hmm. This is another question. It sounds like "How do I select a particular cell in a DataGridView programmatically." Just select it as you mentioned in your _answer_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that preserves the default scrolling behavior of scrolling the viewport, but not changing the row selection.

It also performs much faster than the built-in mouse wheel handler when millions of rows are being handled in a virtual grid:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.MouseWheel += DataGridView1_MouseWheel;
}

private void DataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hme = e as HandledMouseEventArgs;
    hme.Handled = true;

    int displayedRowIndex = DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

    // each "detente" scroll appears to create a delta of 120
    // dividing delta by 120 to get the number of rows scrolled
    // taking the negative of the delta so that it can be added to the displayedRowIndex intuitively as negative is down, positive is up
    var rowDelta = -(e.Delta / 120);

    var newDisplayedRowIndex = e.Delta < 0 ? Math.Min(displayedRowIndex + rowDelta, DataGridView1.RowCount - 1) : Math.Max(displayedRowIndex + rowDelta, 0);

    DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = newDisplayedRowIndex;
}
```