# VB.net Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. DataGridView on Mouse Scroll

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 3 textboxes which is where I put the data to be inserted in datagridview using array

here is my code

```
Dim row As String() = New String() {MetroTextBox12.Text, MetroTextBox11.Text, MetroTextBox13.Text}
MetroGrid9.Rows.Add(row)
MetroTextBox12.Text = ""
MetroTextBox11.Text = ""
MetroTextBox13.Text = ""
```

the problem is when I scroll the datagridview using mouse wheel it shows a ArgumentOutOfRangeException

and here is the stack trace

```
StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex(Int32 value)
       at MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid.OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseWheel(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at ElectronicClientLoanInformationAndPortalSystem.dbSettingsAdder.dbSettingsAdder_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\2020 Program\ECLIPS SOLUTION\ECLIPS\ElectronicClientLoanInformationAndPortalSystem\Common Forms\dbSettingsAdder.vb:line 78
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Maybe this metro grid overrides the mouse wheel method to for example update some custom scrollbars and it does not count the new row? Just a guess. Call `MetroGrid9.EndEdit()` after inserting a new row and try.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953917/13393566) would help.